# Unit Testing and Android DownloadManager

Tags: android, testing

I would like to unit test a class that makes use of the Android DownloadManager service, but I'm not sure how to go about doing it.  Should I actually use the DownloadManager service or is there some way I can mock it up?  I would rather not have my test call an external web server.  Is there an existing testing library I can use for this?

Comment: Hi nil, Did you find any solution for unit test of DownloadManager?

Answer (score 1):

1. This solution use [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org)

One important thing to know is that **the count of Download Manager requests starts at -1**. So if you enqueue a request, the request count gonna be 0.

2. Mock your DownloadManager object
3. Write your test

   ```
   public void shouldEnqueueRequest() {
   //...

   //...

   verify(downloadManager, times(1)).enqueue(anyObject());
   //Is the DownloadManager empty
   assertThat(shadowOf(downloadManager).getRequestCount(), greaterThan(-1));
   //Get the request from the DownloadManager
   ShadowRequest realRequest = shadowOf(shadowOf(downloadManager).getRequest(0));
   assertThat(realRequest, notNullValue());
   assertThat(realRequest.getDescription(), equalTo("Your description"));
   assertThat(realRequest.getTitle(), equalTo(APP_NAME));
   }
   ```